# Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I,m trying to add empty column in my dataset on colab but it give me this error. and when I,m trying to run it on my local machine it works perfectly fine. does anybody know possible solution for this?

My code.

```
dataframe["Comp"] = ''
dataframe["Negative"] = ''
dataframe["Neutral"] = ''
dataframe["Positive"] = ''
dataframe
```

> Error message

TypeError: Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into similar issue today.

> "Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty"

my dataframe(called df) has timeindex. When add a new column to it, and fill with numpy.array data, it raise this error. I tried set it with df.index or df.index.value. It always raise this error.

Finally, I solved by 3 stesp:

1. df = df.reset_index()
2. df['new_column'] = new_column_data # it is np.array format
3. df = df.set_index('original_index_name')

WY

Answer (score 0):

this Quetion is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67997139/16240186, and there's a simple way to solve it: df = df.asfreq('H') # freq can be min\D\M\S\5min etc.