# TypeError: Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty

Tags: python, pandas

I,m trying to add empty column in my dataset on colab but it give me this error.  does anybody know possible solution for this?

My code.

```
dataframe["Comp"] = ''
dataframe["Negative"] = ''
dataframe["Neutral"] = ''
dataframe["Positive"] = ''
dataframe
```

Error message

TypeError: Expected unicode, got pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty

Comment: I load my data set like this "code start"  stocks_dataf = pd.read_pickle('Twitter_Dataset.pkl')   "code end"

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer from Quabr, and it works:

Reason: It's due to `'freq'` of `datetimeindex` was set as "pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty object at 0x7fb22dd1e2c8>"

Solution: used `df = df.asfreq('H')` to set it correctly.